# Which linux should I run on this vintage box?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lightweight GUI Linux distribution for really old computer](https://superuser.com/questions/73912/lightweight-gui-linux-distribution-for-really-old-computer)

I need to install a copy of Linux on my P 550 Mhz Pentium III machine with 256 MB SD Ram. Which distro should I go for ??

Comment: What is the purpose of this machine? Should a desktop environment be installed on it or will this machine be used as a small server?

Answer (score 2):

If you need linux then any one of the above are good choices.  If what you want is linixy/unixy then NetBSD or OpenBSD would be worth looking at.  That said, they are not linux so it's up to you.  I mention this only because I run NetBSD on a similiar sized system as a web proxy, router, and general home server and the speed is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) may suit you well. It's very lightweight and fast.

Comment: Or an LXDE based distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Install Arch linux and install [lightweight apps](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lightweight_Software).

Answer (score 0):

For my router/server (P2, same amount of RAM) I have used Debian for years. I think you would be better off without a window manager.

For desktop use, any distribution works. Using a lightweight window manager here would be more pleasing, performance wise.